# Difference between two kingston RAM chips

Tags: memory, specifications

I'm trying to figure out the difference between two ram chips. The KHX1600C9D3X2K2 and the KHX1600C9D3K2.

Official Specs: [KHX1600C9D3X2K2](http://www.valueram.com/datasheets/khx1600c9d3x2k2_8gx.pdf) and [KHX1600C9D3K2](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/KHX1600C9D3K2_8GX.pdf)

There seems to be no difference at all between the two except for the extra `X2` in the name of the first.
I am asking because I am going to use one of them with an `i7 3770k` and `ASUS P8Z77-V PRO`.

Comment: Yeah they are exactly the same as far as I can tell and both use XMP, so they should be up and running at 1600 CL9 as soon as you set the xmp profile.

Comment: The x2 just reflects the color difference.

Comment: probably reflects a different production run, only has meaning to kingston. Email or call Kingston and ask.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PDFs with specs you provided they are exactly the same.

I suspect that the X2 is an indicated for kits with two modules in them.

This is based on my own memory shopping experiences. Back in the i7 920 time a lot of dual channel kits had X2 in their name, and triple channel kits had X3 in their name.

Comment: The spec sheets both say 2 pcs.

Comment: Aye. And the spec sheets themselves have different numbers. But electrically both sets should be identical. a few years ago the only difference between some modules and kits was that the kits where sold as tested in pairs. To fill 6 slots on a triple channel motherboard you could use three sets of X2, two sets of X3 and over 6 loose modules. And you could get the same modules, except for testing.